# Mysql - unknown variable 'table_cache=64'

Tags: php, mysql, mamp, mamp-pro

I use **Mamp Pro 3**. I upgraded Mamp's MySql to **5.6.24** using this script https://gist.github.com/tobi-pb/b9426db51f262d88515c.

After that I ran the Mamp Pro and MySql cannot be started. So I looked the mysql_error.log and found the following error:

```
2015-06-15 01:24:55 13139 [ERROR] /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld: unknown variable 'table_cache=64'
2015-06-15 01:24:55 13139 [ERROR] Aborting
```

After I google about this error, I get to know that I have to delete '**table_cache=64**' variable from `my.cnf` (MySql Configuration) file. So I deleted this variable from `/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/my.cnf` file.

But the problem is that the same error still occurs when I start the MySql again. So I looked at the `my.cnf` file, '**table_cache=64**' re-appears automatically again. I deleted it again but it automatically appeared again when I start the MySql.

So how should I solve this '**table_cache=64**' problem?

Comment: This might be better on http://dba.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @chris85 thanks. I will also post on dba.stackexchange.com.

Comment: I've requested migration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There may be people who also experience this problem like me. After 3 full days of trying with no success, I gave up to solve this problem with proper way.

I uninstall **MAMP Pro 3** and reset **Mysql** root user's password and then I run my websites with **MAMP free version**. All the problems gone and Mysql version successfully upgraded.

Answer (score 1):

As from MySQL 5.1.3 `table_cache` changed to `table_open_cache`. For details see https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/104025/mysql-unknown-variable-table-cache-64